# kohana 3 uploading image without using any modules?

Tags: php, image, upload, kohana, gd

does anybody have an example of uploading images in kohana 3 without using any modules eventually ?

i used https://github.com/kohana/image/tree/3.1%2Fmaster but my error is: Fatal error: Uncaught Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Installed GD does not support images

is there any easy and fast way to upload files in a kohana 3 based website?

thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Kohana API](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Upload) should help.

Basic steps are:

1. Create Validation object (`$array = Validation::factory($_FILES);`)
2. Define rules (`$array->rule('file', 'Upload::not_empty')->rule('file', 'Upload::type', array(array('jpg', 'png', 'gif')));`)
3. Check file(s) (`if ($array->check())`)
4. And save it (`$filepath = Upload::save($_FILES['file'], 'uploaded_file', 'upload_dir');`)

Answer (score 2):

This will help you :)

http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/6988/ko3-k03-image-library-installed-gd-does-not-support-images/p1