# imagestring function in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

i have a little problem with creating an image and writing a text on it in Kohana.
My code works fine if i use a simple php, but i can't integrat it in Kohana framework controller and action.
when i am doing that in action it retruns me a strange code which i think could be a image bitecode

in my action i have put the headers for image like this

> $this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg';

and then i am coding for simple image creation

> ```
> $image = imagecreate(450,250);
> $color = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
> imagestrig($image,5,34,56,"some txt",$color);
> imagejpeg($image,NULL,100);
> ```

and i am going to this action with this routing url - constructor(controller)/image_creator(action) 
it returns me blabla bla a strange unicode text

does anyone know how to actually create image whit this framework:
i have tried like this, but it also doesn't work:
http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/4412/solved-ko3-gd-and-htmlimage/p1

Actually i am not trying to display it, i don't need to show created image, i want to create image, and then send it to mail, but my script doesn't work, how can i get image in actin and mail it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732221/kohana-3-image-save-and-thumbnail

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204059/output-image-in-a-kohana-3-2-view, also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430449/kohana-3-uploading-image-without-using-any-modules

Comment: actually i am not trying to display it , i don't need to show created image, i want to create image, and then send it to mail, but my script doesn't work, how can i get image in actin and mail it?

Comment: check out http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Image

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552868/kohana-3-1-the-system-does-not-load-email-module for email

Comment: ok, thanks but i don't hav a problem with sending an email with php, or Kohana, the main point is how to get that image, to mail it

Comment: What version of Kohana are you using? Can you post more your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to save this image and then attach to email.

```php
// ...
$imagePath = 'tmp/'.time().uniqid().'.jpg';
imagejpeg($im, $imagePath);

// Attach created image to email (let's assume you're using Swift Mailer)
$m->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($imagePath)->setDisposition('inline'));
// ...send email    

imagedestroy($im);
// Remove image from hard disk
unlink($imagePath);
```